# Can I run Loyal Cathar in my green-white Commander deck?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

I'm running a green white Commander deck and wanted to know if I could.

Answer (score 3):

Alas, you may not. This is because, [per the rules posted on mtgcommander.net](http://mtgcommander.net/rules.php),

> The back face of a double-faced card is included when determining a card's colour identity.

So, while [Loyal Cathar](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLoyal%20Cathar%5d) is a white card, a white spell on the stack, and a white creature on the battlefield (or a black creature when it's flipped), its Commander-specific color identity is actually white+black.